# Laravel many to many relationship with eager

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, many-to-many

I have the following tables:-

```
Table: facilities

Columns:

id bigint(20) UN AI PK 
name varchar(255) 


Table: reports

Columns:

id bigint(20) UN AI PK 
number varchar(20) 
visit_date date 
type varchar(255) 
user_id bigint(20) UN 

Table: observations

Columns:

id bigint(20) UN AI PK 
observation longtext 
recommendation longtext 
priority varchar(255) 
status bigint(20) UN 
report_facility_id bigint(20) UN

Table: report_facility

Columns:

id bigint(20) UN AI PK 
facility_id bigint(20) UN 
report_id bigint(20) UN
```

Models:-

```
class Facility extends Model
{
 
    public function reports()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Report');
    }

   
}

class Report extends Model
{

    public function facilities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Facility','report_facility','report_id','facility_id');
    }
   
}

class ReportFacility extends Model
{

    public function observations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Observation');
    }

    public function visit_details()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\VisitDetail');
    }

    public function facility()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Facility');
        
    }

    public function report()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Report');
    }
}
```

The relationship is Each (Report) has one or many (Facility) and each (Facility) have one or many (Observation).

This is what i am using right now

```
Report::where('number',$number)->first()
        ->load(['facilities' => function($q) {
            $q->with('observations');
        }]);
```

The above is returning (Facility) with loading all the observations related to that facility , instead of loading only observations related to that report .

What is the proper eloquent query to be used to load all reports on DB with their facility and load observations related to each facility written for that report.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the relationships in the `load()` method call.

```
Report::where('number',$number)->first()
        ->load('facilities', 'observations');
```

Comment: Call to undefined relationship [observations] on model [App\Report].

Comment: I think when i separate the relationship as you explained, the observations will be loaded directly under the report, i want it to load as an array , each facility has array of observations

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that observations is not defined on the reports model.

Comment: Try dot notation like `->load('facilities.observations')`

Comment: I tried, it return the same , it return all the observation related to that facility from all reports

Comment: There's nothing directly linking the reports and observations, like a ReportID column on the observations table. Can you create the column and get them linked?
Can you get the results you want when writing an SQL query? If so, you could translate that in to (Laravek query builder code)[https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229575/discussion-between-q8root-and-increda-jaw).

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding the following line to ReportFacility Model:-

```
public function visit_details()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\VisitDetail');
    }
```

And changed the eloquent query to:-

```
Report::where('number',$number)->first()
        ->load('report_facilities.observations');
```